# Dotspacial: Iterate through objects of type Shape instead of ShapeRange

Tags: file, loops, gis, shapes

I am a beginner in using the Dotspacial library. To iterate through the content of a shape file I can read the file with FeatureSet and then iterate with fs.ShapeIndices through Shaperanges to print out the vertexes. Now I also would like to print out the attributes, but ShapeRange does not give me this. Is it possible to iterate through objects of type Shape, where I have this information? Here my code:

```
        IFeatureSet fs = FeatureSet.Open(@"Cabinet.shp");

        foreach (ShapeRange shape in fs.ShapeIndices)
        {
            foreach (PartRange part in shape.Parts)
            {
                foreach (Vertex vertex in part)
                {
                    if (vertex.X > 0 && vertex.Y > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("X:"+vertex.X);
                        Console.WriteLine("Y:" + vertex.Y);
                        //here I want to print attribute values
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```